# Computing Hilbert Class Field.

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ramification

There are some references for computing the Hilbert Class Fields [of quadratic extensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29512/computing-the-hilbert-class-field), and [of cubic extensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/915545/hilbert-class-field-for-pure-cubic-fields).

Q1. Is there a general way to compute the Hilbert Class Fields of cyclotomic extensions?  (i.e. HCF of $k(\zeta_n)$, when HCF($k$) is known.)

---

Also [it is known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175366/complete-splitting-of-a-prime-ideal-in-a-certain-abelian-extension-of-an-algebra) that if $K$ is the Hilbert Class Field of $k$ and $L/k$ is finite Abelian, then $KL$ is contained in the Hilbert Class Field of $L$.

Q2.  How far is the converse true?  I.e., if $L/k$ is finite Abelian, and $M$ is the HCF($L$), then can anything (non-trivial) be said about HCF($k$)?

Edit: Barry Smith's comment suggested that, in order to solve this, we would first need to know:

Q1.5. How far is the HCF of $L$ from just $KL$?

Comment: For Q2, your initial observation is false.  It can be proved separately that 1) $KL$ is abelian over $L$, and 2) $KL$ is unramified over $L$.  That only implies that $KL$ is contained in the Hilbert Class Field of $L$, and indeed, there are cases where it is a proper subfield.